# Firebase rule sets for this specific app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am making a web app with react js that allows users who visit the site to push a data to my firebase database with this structure

```
   -reports
     -unique-key
          details: "Details about this report"
          profile: "https://acme.com/profile/1"
          submitBy: "heydude23"
          thread: "https://www.acme.com/forum/thread/1"
          uid: "151223"

     -unique-key...
```

My question is should i just leave my firebase rules read/write to true? Or it will be bad ? I don't really understand how 'anyone can access your database' with this rule set.. will they be able to delete the datas? I don't want authentication since it's not needed..

Comment: you might find this firebase single-page starter app valuable. Gets you up and running as quick as you can pull the repo into a new web project. https://github.com/rhroyston/foobase

Comment: I don't think they can delete anything, since the project is associated with your email account

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes but i some people said if they go to the website that is running firebase and the read and write is true anyone can run a firebase command on the console to delete the database...i dont know if it will work on a react app or just the plain firebase script tag on the html

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to implement security rules with any app. Without security rules your app may fail or become compromised. For example, doing a `.set()` on the root node deletes the entire database.

Don't forget to have a look at Firestore. It may be a better fit for your app.

There is a [Validating Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data) example showing an example of what you might consider.

Not really a super technical answer but I hope that helps.